# Create a List of type which depends on a string value

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose that I have a .txt file where:

1. the first word is a type or the name of a class (even a class defined by an user). So it could be ANYTHING accepted by the compiler.
2. the following words are value of that type.

As an example:

```
int 1 2 3 5 6 8 19 20
```

How can I create a List of the type of the first word in c#? Something of this kind is obviously illegal, but I'll write it anyway in order to make it clear what I need:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader file = 
            new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt");
            string[] words = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(' ');
            List<words[0]> list = new List<words[0]>;
        }
```

Even if that was possible, the operation `list.add(word[i])` should be anyway a problem (since each element is a string too)!

**Important Note:** reflection is not allowed in the project specifics since the performance are bad!

Comment: Does it have to be one piece of code for all possible types?

Comment: It could be literally "anything"? Then you will have to use either reflection or something even less convenient and more slow. For what it's worth, you can cache reflection-based information, or use the `Expression` class to do some of the same things reflection would be used for here, which other than a small up-front cost should not be any slower than regular code. Compared to the I/O cost of actually reading the data from a disk, I think you'd find any performance hit negligible.

Comment: @ChrisF not necessarily, but why? I repeat, it could be ANYTHING, even classes created by the user!

Comment: @TwistAndShutter - well you could do it a crude way by parsing the string - but that would a) need a different set of code for each type and b) wouldn't be extensible to unknown classes. My recommendation is to use reflection. It's not *that* slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would *strongly* advise against attempting this, at least with the completely unconstrained requirement you've stated.

There are at least a couple of minor, solvable problems:

1. Reflection is required, in spite of your desire to avoid it. There is just no practical way to turn a simple string containing a type name into the data structure you're looking for without reflection. You can minimize performance issues by using a "memoization" pattern (i.e. caching the per-type deserialization objects, to avoid the overhead of going through reflection for every line of input), as well as using `Expression`s to build the cached deserialization objects (which will ensure the best performance possible when actually processing the data).
2. There is no general purpose way to parse a string value to create an instance of some arbitrary type. You can address this partially, by checking the type itself for some method that could be used to accomplish the task. E.g. use reflection to look for a method named "Parse", and use that method to convert strings to type instances. But obviously this will not work with types missing such a method; this irreconcilably blocks the possibility of literally handling *any* possible type.

There are also a number of much more significant problems (i.e. extremely difficult or impossible to solve):

1. Your example isn't even going to work, because `int` is not an actual .NET type name. You would have to special-case C# type aliases like `int`, `bool`, `long`, etc. to get that to work.
2. Even using reflection (which is the right way to go), you still will need fully-qualified type names to reliably deal with this. It's entirely possible, for example, for an executing `AppDomain` to have multiple types named `Point`. Without the namespace, there's no way to effectively resolve the ambiguity.
3. Given a fully-qualified type name, .NET will by default search only the executing assembly and mscorlib.dll for a given type. You'll have to do the search yourself if you want to find types in other assemblies. You obviously will only be able to handle, at best, types contained in assemblies referenced by the `AppDomain`'s entry point assembly. To handle assemblies referenced indirectly, you will need to search the assembly types recursively to find the type name you're looking for. Obviously, types in unknown assemblies cannot be handled.
4. It's not clear at all from your question just how you expect to *use* this generic list of these objects. It's well and good to use generics, e.g. to ensure type safety. But using a `List<T>` for some specific type is generally very inconvenient if you can't actually declare a variable that's actually of the `List<T>` type for the specific type that was read.
5. Probably one of the biggest problems is that not all types can be represented as space-delimited values! Consider, for example, what you expect the input text to look like if the type name is `System.String`. If any string value itself has a space in it, that will be mistaken for a value delimiter, corrupting the data when it's parsed.

Some of the issues above can be addressed by constraining the problem. For example, requiring each type to implement a static `Parse()` method, requiring each type to be referenced by one of the assemblies in the process, limiting the possible values of the type, or providing additional rules for delimiting or otherwise formatting values in the text, etc. But these work only if you're willing to back off from the original, broad specification you've stipulated in your question.

Ideally, you would simply know ahead of time which types you might need to parse, and then you would write specific code for each type. This is most reliable, albeit more time-consuming.

A variation on this theme which might work in your scenario is to use the [Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) (or similar technique) to provide for an add-in mechanism, in which type-specific add-ins are provided which know how to parse a line of input. Each add-in would publish a name (which need not be an actual real type name…it just needs to be unique), and then your program would retrieve the appropriate add-in to parse the line based on the unique name provided at the beginning of the line (as in your example).

Bottom line: as stated, taking the specification at its literal word, this just cannot be done in any reasonable way.

You're going to have to limit the scope of the requirement at least somewhat, to facilitate an actual solution. I've offered some general guidance above as to how that might work, if you do in fact limit the scope of your requirement. Please feel free to ask new questions about the individual parts of the problem, if you have trouble figuring out how to do them.

Answer (score 2):

You just can't do this in C# without involving runtime reflection of some manner.

Perhaps the most practical way to do something close to what you ask, and which does not explicitly involve reflection is to use `dynamic`:

```
var t = typeof(int); // or some other type based on the input
dynamic list = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t));
```

You can then simply use `list.Add(x)` where `x` is a value of the appropriate type -- but you have to somehow convert the input to that type as well -- you can't just add the strings you read from the file.

The latter is a problem perhaps even more difficult to solve than creating and using the list itself: how do you turn a string (which is what you always read from the file) into a value of some arbitrary type specified by the user?